# D3 Autocomplete change div to input box

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm wanting to change the source code of an auto-completer that I found on the D3 site.

[Click here for link](http://www.brightpointinc.com/clients/brightpointinc.com/library/autocomplete/index.html?source=d3js)

I basically want to turn the `<div id="test" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>` code into a html form input box so when you click on the autocompleted item it will process a "submit" type request.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question and what you want to do, you can replace the `div` with `input` using JavaScript by doing something like this :

```
var toReplace = document.getElementById('test'); //element to be replaced
var parent = toReplace.parentNode;

var input = document.createElement('input'); // new element
input.id = input.name = "test";
input.type = 'text';
// can declare more attributes for input here

parent.replaceChild(input, toReplace);  // Replacing here..
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LqmLvkgw/)